# Find position of point after scaling (OpenGL and C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, position, scaling, point

I've created a program that draws points to the screen in OpenGL (It draws the letter "X" at a specific point). The drawing is then scaled based on user input.

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
{
    /*"zoom" is a global float variable*/
    zoom += 0.005;
}

glScaled(1 + zoom, 1 + zoom, 1);
```

I want to find the new position of the points relative to the screen (i.e. A point may be drawn at (100, 100) but after scaling it may be somewhere like (150, 200) with regard to the screen coordinates, but the rasterisation values are always the same, in this case (100, 100)). Is there a function in OpenGL that can return the new coordinates of a point based on specific scaling?

Comment: The scaled coordinates are just [x * (1+zoom), y * (1+zoom), z], so there's no need for a special OpenGL function.

Comment: `glScaled (...)` creates a scaling matrix and then multiplies your "current" matrix by it. In other words, it basically multiplies input points by a scale matrix. You can compute the inverse matrix and multiply by that to go the other direction (from scaled back to original coordinates). Thinking about it that way is more complicated than it needs to be, but it at least gives you an idea of what's going on under the hood.